# Incompatibility of the ocg-p package with the ocgcolorlinks option of the hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, ocg, ocg-p

When I use the option `ocgcolorlinks` of the `hyperref` package together with the package `ocg-p` (**MiKTeX** + **pdflatex**), it looks like the `ocgcolorlinks` option becomes not working anymore (independently of the order of inclusion of the packages). When `ocg-p` is excluded from the code, all links become printed again in the default text color.

Is this problem described somewhere? Or, maybe, someone can suggest, what I have to do to combine in one code the option `ocgcolorlinks` and the package `ocg-p`?

MWE (provided by cyberSingularity):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ocg-p}% uncomment this, and print preview to see the problem
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    See \autoref{next}
    \section{Next}
    \label{next}
    Target.
\end{document}
```

Print preview when `ocg-p` loaded (left) and not loaded (right):

[image: ocg-p loaded] [image: ocg-p not loaded]

Comment: I have edited your question to include what I consider to be a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. In future, please try to do this yourself. Also, we don't usually put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both packages, [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and [`ocg-p`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ocg-p), try to create optional content groups (OCGs) without knowing from one another. This results in incorrect PDF files (to be more specific, duplicate `/OCProperties` and `/Properties` entries), which prevent the OCGs from working as expected.

It is not particularly easy to make the two packages cooperate, as the implementations are completely independent. The following code should work for the current versions `hyperref v6.83m` and `ocg-p v0.4`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ocg-p}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}

% Fix incompability between ocg-p and the hyperref option ocgcolorlinks
% (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104227)
\makeatletter
\Hy@colorlinkstrue
\Hy@ocgcolorlinksfalse
\newcommand*{\reenable@ocglinks@pdftex}{%
  \Hy@AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Hy@colorlink##1{%
      \begingroup
        \def\Hy@ocgcolor{##1}%
        \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\color@begingroup
    }%
    \def\Hy@endcolorlink{%
      \color@endgroup\egroup
      \mbox{%
        \pdfliteral page{/OC/OCPrint BDC}%
        \rlap{\copy0}%
        \pdfliteral page{EMC/OC/OCView BDC}%
        \begingroup
          \expandafter\HyColor@UseColor\Hy@ocgcolor
          \box0 %
        \endgroup
        \pdfliteral page{EMC}%
      }%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm}{%
  \Hy@AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Hy@colorlink##1{%
      \begingroup
        \def\Hy@ocgcolor{##1}%
        \setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\color@begingroup
    }%
    \def\Hy@endcolorlink{%
      \color@endgroup\egroup
      \mbox{%
        \@pdfm@mark{content /OC/OCPrint BDC}%
        \rlap{\copy0}%
        \@pdfm@mark{content EMC/OC/OCView BDC}%
        \begingroup
          \expandafter\HyColor@UseColor\Hy@ocgcolor
          \box0 %
        \endgroup
        \@pdfm@mark{content EMC}%
      }%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}
\def\Hy@temp{hpdftex}
\ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
  \reenable@ocglinks@pdftex
\else
  \def\Hy@temp{hdvipdfm}
  \ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
    \reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm
  \else
    \def\Hy@temp{hxetex}
    \ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
      \reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
\@ocgp@newocg{View}{View}{1}{printocg=never,listintoolbar=never}
\@ocgp@newocg{Print}{Print}{0}{printocg=always,listintoolbar=never}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}
    See \autoref{next}
    \section{Next}
    \label{next}
    Target.
\end{document}
```

### Explanation of the code

We deliberately disable the `ocgcolorlinks` feature  to stop the interference with the OCG management provided by the `ocg-p` package:

```
\Hy@colorlinkstrue
\Hy@ocgcolorlinksfalse
```

Now we re-enable the necessary OCG markup of the hyperlinks by hand. For the three drivers currently supporting `ocgcolorlinks` (`pdftex`, `dvipdfm` and `xetex`), different code is necessary (cf. [`hpdftex.def`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def), ll. 292-318, [`hdvipdfm.def`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvipdfm.def), ll. 280-306, and [`hxetex.def`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def), ll. 362-388):

```
\newcommand*{\reenable@ocglinks@pdftex}{%
  % see above
}
\newcommand*{\reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm}{%
  % see above
}
\def\Hy@temp{hpdftex}
\ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
  \reenable@ocglinks@pdftex
\else
  \def\Hy@temp{hdvipdfm}
  \ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
    \reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm
  \else
    \def\Hy@temp{hxetex}
    \ifx\Hy@driver\Hy@temp
      \reenable@ocglinks@dvipdfm
    \fi
  \fi
\fi
```

At last, we create the optional content groups `View` and `Print` with the necessary visibility options using `ocg-p`:

```
\@ocgp@newocg{View}{View}{1}{printocg=never,listintoolbar=never}
\@ocgp@newocg{Print}{Print}{0}{printocg=always,listintoolbar=never}
```

Like this, the OCGs are introduced correctly to the PDF viewer, avoiding misguiding duplicate definitions.

Comment: I took your code and [extended it to the `dvips+ps2pdf` route](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231626), based on a single `\reenable@ocglinks` command for all drivers. Thanks for sorting out the relevant code in `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2):

Package `ocgx2`, v0.17 [2016/03/22], reimplements `hyperref`'s `ocgcolorlinks` option, borrowing from diabonas' code. Moreover, it ports Layers and the `ocgcolorlinks` option to other engines where they haven't been available before.

Thus, to have both, coloured links that print in the colour of the surrounding text and working PDF Layers, just say

```
\usepackage{hyperref} % do NOT set [ocgcolorlinks] here!
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Do NOT set [ocgcolorlinks] here!
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

\begin{document}

  \section{Test}
  See \autoref{next}

  \section{Next}
  \label{next}
  Target.

  \begin{ocg}{some layer}{some_layer}{1}
  \noindent Text on a PDF layer
  \end{ocg}

  \noindent\toggleocgs{some_layer}{\fbox{Click}} to toggle visibility.

\end{document}
```