# hyperref with ocgcolorlinks option & dvips/ps2pdf

Tags: hyperref, dvips, dvi-mode, ocg

In my PDF document, while opened in the PDF viewer (AR), I would like to have coloured text as hyperlinks instead of boxes.

So I set the package option `ocgcolorlinks` with `hyperref`, because links should come out as black (the default text colour) when printed on paper.

However, if I run `latex` on my document source (I am using the `dvips`+`ps2pdf` route) I get the warning message

> ```
> Package hyperref Warning: Driver does not support `ocgcolorlinks',
> (hyperref)                using `colorlinks' instead on input line 66.
> ```

and I get coloured link text on paper.

[Recently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128511), Ghostscript was added support for OCGs (PDF Layer). In theory, it should now be possible to make the `ocgcolorlinks` option functional with `dvips`+`ps2pdf`.

How difficult would it be to implement this? Moreover, it would be nice to make `ocgcolorlinks` compatibile with the `ocgx` and `ocg-p` packages at the same time, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104227) for the other workflows (`dvipdfmx`, `xelatex`). (Those packages are used to put text on PDF layers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Option `ocgcolorlinks` has been made available for use with `dvips`+`ps2pdf` through pkg `ocgx2`:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}
```

---

<s>This implements the `ocgcolorlinks` option for `hyperref` for use with `dvips`+`ps2pdf`.</s>

Now, `ocgcolorlinks` works with all known drivers/engines. Also, the incompatibility with the PDF-Layer producing packages `ocgx` and `ocg-p` is fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{ocg-p}

% this loads ocg-p automatically; enables OCGs for dvips/ps2pdf (GS-9.15)
\usepackage{ocgx}\usepackage{fixocgx}

\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}

...
```